# Why null value of two List modify hashcode differently?

Tags: java, list, hashcode

I have two lists. After inserting the same value, its `hashCode` is same.

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(1);
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(1);

System.out.println(list1.hashCode()==list2.hashCode()); // It print true
```

Regarding above example I have one question:

- Why hashCode is same in two different `List`s?

Comment: What you say sounds pretty unlikely. Please show an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @NPE  Correct. It's not even reproduced. Here is the proof.  https://ideone.com/Vl9tfw

Comment: Which JVM you are using? I use Oracle Hot Spot and both print TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

The contract on `hashCode` is that if two objects compare equal, their hash codes must also be equal (the converse does not have to hold).

This means that the second behaviour would be non-compliant. If your JDK does indeed behave like that (mine doesn't), you should file a bug with the JDK's vendor.

Comment: In addition the javadoc for `List.hashcode` specifies a *formula* for calculating the value.

Answer (score 2):

See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/List.java#List.hashCode%28%29):

```
539    public int hashCode() {
540        int hashCode = 1;
541        for (E e : this)
542            hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
543        return hashCode;
544    }
```

You have two lists having `null`, according to the source code, you should get the same `hashcode` in both cases, if not, something is wrong with your JDK.

Comment: Also see the javadoc.  This is NOT just an implementation detail.

Comment: @StephenC Isn't it the same as the Javadoc? What I though is that if `e` is `null`, then he'll get 0 for both values.. thus the result must be equal. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun: what Stephen C wanted to say is that the javadoc of the `List` *interface* specifies how the hash code has to look like. So you don’t have to look at the source code of a particular implementation. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode()

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Yes ... that is what I was trying to say.  If it was *just* the code, then different versions of that particular class could use different algorithms.  But, since it is in the javadoc (and the `List` javadoc at that!) this is part of the Java class library *specification*, and therefore *must* be the same in all (compliant) implementations, and for all 3rd party classes that (correctly) implement that interface.